# Override HTTP Authorization Manager in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a test configured in Jmeter for a HTTP basic auth-protected site. I have an HTTP Authorization Manager configured at the top level with the user/pass for this auth.

There's one http request buried deep in the thread ('Get configurable product options' in the pic below) that I do not want to send the Authorization header with: it's a REST call and I'm sending a bearer Authorization header instead.

I have a HTTP Header Manager assigned to this call with the specific Authorization header defined. All I want is for the Basic Auth header not to be sent, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how.

How do I override this so that the Authorization header set by the HTTP Header Manager overrides the one set by the Authorization Manager?

[image: The 'Get configurable product options' http request needs a different Authorization header to everything else]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) for the HTTP Authorization Manager (JMeter 5.0)

> If there is more than one Authorization Manager in the scope of a Sampler, there is currently no way to specify which one is to be used.

So the only way you can override the [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header value is using [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)

1. Add HTTP Header Manager **as a child** which header you want to override
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Name: `Authorization`
   - Value: `${__base64Encode(username:password,)}`

     **Replace `username` and `password` with your real credentials**

Keep in mind that [__base64Encode()](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#base64Encodesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-2-0-font-sup) is a **custom** JMeter function, if you don't have it already you will need to install it via [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)